# Facebook comment box for each articles

Tags: facebook, plugins

I have created an facebook comment box,here's the question,if user's adding comment from random articles on the website,the comment will not shown as they comment from articles,but for whole site.how could I make this facebook comment for each articles?thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript, the script remains the same for each articles. It looks like:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YOUR_APP_ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

As for the HTML, you'll have to update the `data-href` attribute depending on the page (article) where you are.

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com/CURRENT_ARTICLE" data-width="470" data-num-posts="2"></div>
```

Comment: I'm using zend,if I'm use <?php echo $this->url(); ?>
would it be the same?